# Issues running Chain-index on WSL2 - fully syncing but not running the webserver

Tags: plutus, plutus-pioneer-program, cabal, plutus-pab

I've run into an issue with the chain-index while trying to run a PAB testnet environment. The index will start up, sync to 100%, update to new blocks, but the webserver will never start. In fact, the port that the chain-index is supposed to occupy remains empty throughout this process. Commmands like `curl -s localhost:9083/tip | jq '.tipSlot.getSlot'` return nothing.

After some debugging, I isolated this piece of code - this is the last piece of code that runs after starting the chain-index server:

```
withAsync (runLogEffects (convertLog PrettyObject trace) $ logProgress chan) wait
```

It seems to log the output of the chain-index's progress, but I'm not sure. I believe it's responsible for outputs like this on the console:

`[chain-index:Info:39] [2022-03-06 10:13:17.47 UTC] Still in sync. Applied 13 blocks, 0 rollbacks in the last 300s. Current tip is Point(Slot 52192355, BlockId 1893367e3a8139b6866e4c6e81bb1d2ecfa80660b1b027785f05d3e309a2d6d6)`

That was a real output from my chain-index server - and proof that it's updating to the current testnet slot (at the time of this post).

This is the full block of code with the problematic line:

```
runMain :: CM.Configuration -> Config.ChainIndexConfig -> IO ()
runMain logConfig config = do
  withRunRequirements logConfig config $ \runReq -> do

    putStr "\nThe tip of the local node: "
    slotNo <- getTipSlot config
    print slotNo

    -- Channel for broadcasting 'ChainSyncEvent's
    chan <- newBroadcastTChanIO
    syncHandler
      <- defaultChainSyncHandler runReq
        & storeFromBlockNo (fromCardanoBlockNo $ Config.cicStoreFrom config)
        & writeChainSyncEventToChan convertEventToSyncStats chan

    putStrLn $ "Connecting to the node using socket: " <> Config.cicSocketPath config
    syncChainIndex config runReq syncHandler

    putStrLn $ "Connected to node socket."

    (trace :: Trace IO (PrettyObject SyncLog), _) <- setupTrace_ logConfig "chain-index"
    putStrLn $ "Trace completed." -- Added
    withAsync (runLogEffects (convertLog PrettyObject trace) $ logProgress chan) wait
    putStrLn $ "Async completed." -- Added

    let port = show (Config.cicPort config)
    putStrLn $ "Starting webserver on port " <> port
    putStrLn $ "A Swagger UI for the endpoints are available at "
            <> "http://localhost:" <> port <> "/swagger/swagger-ui"
    Server.serveChainIndexQueryServer (Config.cicPort config) runReq
```

I have two theories, but otherwise don't really know where to go from here.

1. There are some issues with running an Async function in WSL2 (unlikely as I see Async functions in other, working Plutus apps)
2. The database is corrupted somehow, and the line of code shown above is parsing through it in an attempt to fix it. I've tried rebuilding the database three times (using different commits on Github) to no avail.

Node version:

```
cardano-node 1.33.0 - linux-x86_64 - ghc-8.10
git rev 814df2c146f5d56f8c35a681fe75e85b905aed5d
```